# Multiple applications running with docker

Tags: php, symfony, docker

I have a symfony application running with docker following this repository 
https://github.com/maxpou/docker-symfony and everything is ok.

But now I am starting another symfony project and I cloned the same docker-symfony repository, but I get this error doing `docker-compose up -d`

> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint
>   symfony2restapidocker_nginx_1
>   (d736a2c930368e1cd94f71e502bfe3ffb991cf8d63ae0b0d412c189c8e5b504f):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated

Is it not possible to have two applications running at the same time each with its docker?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to manage which containers are running at the same time, Portainer may be useful.  The first container will need to be stopped if you also want to use port 80 for your second container.

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is already allocated for some other application/service. 
Try to stop 80 port running application. otherwise you can change it your current application port to some other like 
Instead of 80 use other port number 7080, etc. something else

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

The error that you are encoutering is caused by the port 80 being already reserved for the first nginx container. If you want to start the same container you need to give it a new port on the host.

The docker-compose file must be updated for the second run as such:

```
version: '2'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        volumes:
            - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    php:
        build:
            context: php7-fpm
            args:
                TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
        volumes:
            - ${SYMFONY_APP_PATH}:/var/www/symfony
            - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
    nginx:
        build: nginx
        ports:
            - 82:80
        volumes_from:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    elk:
        image: willdurand/elk
        ports:
            - 83:80
        volumes:
            - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
            - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns
        volumes_from:
            - php
            - nginx
```

In this case, port 82 and 82 will be reserved for the new containers nginx and elk respectively.

Comment: I just modified the ports. The "docker-compose up -d" is ok for both projects, but second php app return contents of the first app